# l1 regularizer in Keras gives error "'Tensor' object is not callable"

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to apply `l1` regularization to a neural network. When done on the first layer there is no problem, but then it is done to the second layer it raises a `TypeError`. Then, if I compile the NN again, the error is raised in the first layer.

The code is as follows:

```
from keras.regularizers import l1
from keras.layers import LSTM,Input
from keras.models import Model

inputs = Input(shape=(window+1,features))

l1 = LSTM(512,return_sequences=True,kernel_regularizer=l1(0.001),recurrent_regularizer=l1(0.001),
        bias_regularizer=l1(0.001),recurrent_activation="sigmoid",activation="relu")(inputs)

l3 = LSTM(512,return_sequences=False,kernel_regularizer=l1(0.001),recurrent_regularizer=l1(0.001), 
        bias_regularizer=l1(0.001),recurrent_activation="sigmoid",activation="relu")(l1)

outputs = LSTM(1,return_sequences=False,kernel_regularizer=l1(0.001),recurrent_regularizer=l1(0.001),
        bias_regularizer=l1(0.001),recurrent_activation="sigmoid",activation="relu")(l3)

model = Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss="mse",optimizer="adam")

TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
```

When just the l1 regularizer is just imported, if I do `type(l1)` it tells me that its a `function` type, but after the error is raised if I do `type(l1)` it tells me its `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor`.

Why is this and how I can solve it? Or I missed something when applying `l1` regularizer? When applying `l2` regularizer I can do it without any problem.

Comment: you assigned `l1` to your LSTM layer

Comment: Ok...I feel pretty dumb now hahahahaha can I delete this question now? hahahahahahaa

Comment: you should actually delete it because it's off topic (caused by a typo) and it will land in a deletion queue and moderators will waste time on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined an `LSTM` with name `l1`, it overrides the function you imported (also named `l1`).